# Java reads wrong values from binary structured file

Tags: java, file, delphi, structure, endianness

I have a file which consist of Delphi records. The record looks like:

```
TPoint = record
    X, Y: Double;
end;
```

As I know Delphi stores data as LittleEndian, and Java as BigEndian so the read method looks like:

```
public Point readPoint() throws IOException {
        double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(
                                Long.reverseBytes(
                                        Double.doubleToLongBits(in.readDouble()
                                        )
                                )
        );
        double y = Double.longBitsToDouble(
                Long.reverseBytes(
                        Double.doubleToLongBits(in.readDouble()
                        )
                )
        );
        return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Everything seemed to be fine but sometimes I take the corrupted data. I got

```
638 offset: 10256   Point{x=3.143E-319, y=48.47134}
```

But should to get

```
638 offset: 10256   Point{x=22.25315, y=48.47134}
```

When I opened the file and look the data with offset 10256 I see:

> 7F FB 3A 70 CE 40 36 40

which is 22.25315 in LittleEndian. So i wondered what is the problem? Is there any problem with Long.reverseBytes() method? Or it's impossible to convert any doubles from LE to BE and vice versa?

Comment: Why are you reading a double to start with? Surely you'd be better off using `Long.reverseBytes(in.readLong())`.

Comment: I have to agree. If you read the double with the bytes in the wrong order, it is possible that there is some normalization that occurs which is changing the bits before you get them to reverse them.

Comment: Added this as an answer, given that I suspect it's the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem *may* be because you're reading 8 bytes as a big-endian `double` when they're *not* a big-endian double. Given that bits have specific meanings in `double`, that could cause problems - Java may be normalizing NaN values, for example. It's a bit like reading text data using an encoding that you *know* is incorrect, and then converting it back into bytes...

If you read the value as a `long` to start with, that should preserve all the bits, so you can reverse the bytes and *then* convert to a `double`:

```
double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.reverseBytes(in.readLong()));
double y = Double.longBitsToDouble(Long.reverseBytes(in.readLong()));
```

Comment: doubleToLongBits *definetly* changes NaN to a canonical representation, its explicitly stated to do so in the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits-double-

Answer (score 1):

Have found the bug. Instead of

```
Long.reverseBytes(Double.doubleToLongBits(in.readDouble())
```

just needed to read as follows:

```
Long.reverseBytes(in.readLong())
```